# Showing apps with in-app billing in countries without paid apps

Tags: android, google-play, billing, in-app

I have just published an app in android market that uses in-app billing. My app can function just good without payment. In other words purchasing in-app products is optional. But I was told that people in countries that has no support of paid apps can't see my app. The app itself is free and I chose it to be available to all countries worldwide while publishing. Does anyone have a trick to make it visible in all countries?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you select all countries while uploading or publishing the application on android market. if you select the all country then it will show in every country. tell me your application name i will check in my country it is available or not.

Comment: yes, I selected all countries.
Here is the app https://market.android.com/details?id=com.online_brain.whereareyou

Comment: the url is unreachable, at least from Spain